# In Android, is there a way to use dynamic string objects to pull down resources?

Tags: android

I have a project that has a ton of avatars. Right now, I have 20+ pictures that will be available to the user using a combination of spinner selections. Right now, there are 20 combinations they can make from just two spinners. This number will grow as I get more art assets.

Is there a way to take the selections they have and programatically choose the correct picture from the resources?

If they choose "sportscar" on the first spinner and "red" on the second spinner, I want to take those two values and load up "sportscar_red.png" by passing the strings to the next activity.

Is there any way to do this?

If not, is there something better than having a disgustingly huge cascading "if/else if" statement?

Edit: Avoiding long "if/else if" statements through other means of tedious hard-coding does not seem to gain any ground with this problem. My main priority when choosing a secondary solution is something that is easy to maintain and scale.

Comment: There's an awesome data structure called HashMap ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a resource ID just from the resource name, with no map, the fastest way is with a method like this:

```
    private int getResourceId(@NonNull String drawableName) {
        int resourceId = -1;
        try {
            Field field = com.your.package.R.drawable.class.getField(drawableName);
            resourceId = field.getInt(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Drawable id not found
        }
        return resourceId;
    }
```

So, when you have the two `String`s from the spinners, simply call:

`int resId = getResourceId(string1 + "_" + string2)`

And that will return the resource ID you need to display, or -1 if it could not be found. No need for hardcoded `Map`s or if/else statements.

Other alternatives to dynamic resource names, like `Resources.getIdentifier()`, are actually slower because they perform more reflection calls in the backgound. A good read on the subject by Daniel Lew can be found [here](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com.au/2009/12/dynamically-retrieving-resources-in.html)

Comment: Will try this soon. Looks like the exact solution I want!

Comment: It's without doubt the most performant option, and still enables you to easily provide alternative resources for different densities. I'd encourage you to read the article I linked for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a HashMap if you can, have the spinner as the key, the drawable as the value. Load 'em up when you need.

```
static Map<String, Integer> icons = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

static 
{
    icons.add("icon1", R.drawable.icon);
    icons.add("icon2", R.drawable.icon2);
    icons.add("icon3", R.drawable.icon3);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just push the problem of having to hardcode the resource loading to a little earlier in the code?  The ideal solution is a way that I can add a new picture to my resource folder (say an orange sports car) and add the new color to my yaml file (add the string "orange") and call it a day.  The spinner reads from the yaml file and adds the "orange" entry at load-time. The activity aggregates the strings "orange" and "sportscar" after the user has made their selection and the app loads "orange_sportscar.png"

Comment: Second comment: not trying to be rude, I just don't see much of an advantage to that method at the moment.

Comment: Either way it's not the best way since bindings would be better, but it looks like the OP just wants a solution that works quickly.

Comment: OP here: I just want maintainability and scalability. If a long list of hard-coding is as good as it gets, I will run with it, but I want to know if I can head this off at the pass first.

Comment: Unless you're using polymorphism with one object per item you have --- that have both a `toString` and `getResourceID`, the map is the second best way to do it.

Comment: With the spinner case, look up the key that they select and always just do load(map.getvalue(key))

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you describe it in your question is the solution already.

Use the value returned from each spinner, combine them using a StringBuilder and use that String to get the image.

For this to work, you need to:
 - Have a very strong naming structure and stick to it.
 - Don't get the value from the spinner using getText because this would prevent you from using multiple languages in your app. You need to be able to get the id value from the String rather than the string itself.

Then you pass the string in Intent. No problem there.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `/assets` folder instead of `/res` and load `drawable`s for your avatars directly.

`String avatarName = firstSpinner + '_' + secondSpinner + '.png';
 Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open("avatars/" + avatarName), null);`

Comment: This has a performance overhead, and removes the native support for multiple densities, but can be a viable alternative in particular cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use following, it's already build in android resource class:

```
public static int getDrawableResId(Context context, String name)
{
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
}
```

Just use it like following:

```
int selectedResource = getDrawableResId(context, "sportscar_red");
```

**Supporting multiple languages with a special adapter (as someone mentioned it)**

For supporting multiple languages, use a special data structure in your spinners, that provides the name of the selected part AND the localised display name... Something like following should work:

```
class Part
{
    private String mName;
    private String mDisplayName;

    public Part(Context c, String name, int displayNameRes)
    {
         mName = name;
         mDisplayName = c.getString(displayNameRes);
    }

    public String getName()
    {
         return mName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    { 
         return mName; // will be used by a simple text spinner adapter... so you don't need to write a custom adapter if you just want to display a simple text, BUT use a custom class
    }
}
```

Now you can create the `ArrayAdapter` with following list:

```
ArrayList<Part> cars = new ArrayList<>();
cars.add(new Part(context, "sportscar", R.string.sportscar));
...
```

**Problem with the `getField` approach**

It will fail if the resource is named like "text.text"... And as there is a native support for retrieving resources by name it's not necessary...

Comment: `Resources.getIdentifier` is a lot slower than using `getField`, which is why reflection is recommended if you care about performance. Resources cannot contain full stops, so it will also work for every case where `getIdentifier` works. The "native support" is actually doing more reflection calls than using `getField` directly, and has the same limitations, if you look at the source code.